# How to mock applog for Junits

Tags: junit, spring-boot-test

Actually I am writing **junits** for a class using `@Autowired AppLog` .

And using `this.applog.logInfo("field",+object.getFieldName())`, they are trying to print values.

I am not getting how to mock this thing.

I am already using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Can powerMock help in this case? I Will be thankful if someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring we have a class know as `[ReflectionTestUtils][1]` which can be utilized if you are testing classes with dependencies. In this case as we have applog autowired.

So, we under `@Before` annotation method can define:

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instanceOfClassWeAreTesting,"appLog",mockedApplogInstance)`.

Hope it help if someone face any issue in future.

Comment: This i have implemented myself and works.Will be happy for other solutions